# How to specify the macOS deployment target for a library?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm building a AU audio plugin for macOS that links against a static Rust library compiled with Cargo. I compile my plugin via CMake with a macOS deployment target set to 10.9. At link time, I get tons of errors like

```
ld: warning: object file (my/rust/libfoo.a (std-bd716fa574aff005.std.8vdpzfpj-cgu.15.rcgu.o)) was built for newer macOS version (10.15) than being linked (10.9)
```

A tester running MacOS 10.13 confirmed that loading the plug-in leads to a crash.

I need to compile the Rust library for a macOS deployment target of 10.9 too, but how do I do that?

The library I'm compiling is resvg, I modified the projects `Cargo.toml` to output a static library in my own fork, which you will find [here](https://github.com/JanosGit/resvg/tree/staticlib/c-api).

I invoke `cargo build --release` and my static library is compiled.

Running

```
otool -l libresvg.a | rg LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX -A2 | sort | uniq
```

outputs

```
  cmdsize 16
  version 10.15
  version 10.7
```

Comment: Creating a brand new static library and using `otool -l target/debug/libdemo.a | rg LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX -A2 | sort | uniq` to investigate it shows that it is `version 10.7`. Please provide a [MRE] that demonstrates how your version is different.

Comment: Thank you for that hint, I edited the original post.

Comment: *I invoke `cargo build --release`* — I'm guessing that CMake is setting the environment variable for you, but to the wrong value. Perform some CMake debugging to see what the environment variables actually are. Perhaps write a script that dumps the env vars to a file before calling `cargo`.

Comment: Building the library is not part of the CMake build process but was performed once in a shell script. I updated my script to output to unset `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`, which generated a library which now generates at least less such linker errors. However the linker still throws a lot of errors for Skia symbols (the resvg library itself contains a striped down version of Skia) so this really seems like a quite specific issue to this library. Therefore I'll create an issue on the resvg GitHub repository

Answer (score 1):

Rust [targets macOS 10.7 by default](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.47.0/src/librustc_target/spec/apple_base.rs#L8-L15) for x86 and x86_64 targets (11.0 for aarch64 targets):

```
% cargo new --lib demo

% cd demo

% echo '[lib]' >> Cargo.toml

% echo 'crate-type = ["staticlib"]' >> Cargo.toml

% unset MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET

% cargo build

# Older versions of macOS and/or x86 and x86_64
% otool -l target/debug/libdemo.a | rg LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX -A2 | rg version | sort | uniq -c
 198   version 10.7

# Newer versions of macOS and/or aarch64
% otool -l target/debug/libdemo.a | rg LC_BUILD_VERSION -A4 | rg minos | sort | uniq -c
```

You can opt into supporting a *newer* version by specifying the `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` environment variable:

```
% export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.12

% cargo clean && cargo build

% otool -l target/debug/libdemo.a | rg LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX -A2 | rg version | sort | uniq -c
   2   version 10.12
 196   version 10.7
```

If you needed to target something *older* than 10.7, I'd expect that you'd have to recompile the Rust standard library itself.

Comment: Building the demo this way correctly compiles a static library for a deployment target of 10.7 so this seems to be specific to the library I'm trying to build